# how to make regex string to match domain and url

Tags: php, regex, url, dns, preg-match

I want to make a php script that will check a text file or a string if it contains a url or domain.

I would like to ask how to make a regex to match url. I would like to match the following strings:

example.com 
example.com.ca 
example.co.uk 
www.example.com 
www.example.com.ca 
www.example.co.uk 
m.example.com 
mobile.example.com 
sample-example.com 
mobi.m.example.co.uk 
mobi-m.example.co.uk

and all the other possible domain/url just without the http://, https://, ftp:// etc.

Comment: If you simply want to check if a hostname is valid you might want to take a look at [gethostbyname](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php).

Comment: hey ccKep. I will update my question. I totally forgot to add this. sorry.

Comment: @HamZa It is not duplicate with the question you regarded. Here he meant only with the protocol section of the URL.

Comment: @sємsєм don't tell me that it's difficult to add one line of regex to that accepted answer ? Anyways, I don't like most questions that don't show any efforts. It's like asking me to do the OP's work.

Comment: @HamZa In many cases, some developers deal with regex as the majority of car's drivers dealing with automobiles mechanics. i.e just the piece that the code need it.

Comment: @HamZa if you don't want to answer my question then don't do it. I am new to programming. and if you don't know, before I ask a question here, I find answers to my questions first. But I don't have one, all the solutions I have didn't work. All the best answers here don't work, maybe I don't know how to put it in my script. And sorry for my question that you think it don't have efforts, I just don't know how to put my questions in mind into words.

Comment: @JAlex I don't want to answer your question since it doesn't contain any sign that you did try something. Your question is clear, but it lacks code that you have tried/searched. I mean if I give you directly the solution, what will you learn from it ? You'll most likely copy paste it and come back again whenever you'll encounter a small problem with it. I'll admit that the task is a bit hard, I mean how will you prevent matches like `troll.lol` or `mr.me` ? Have you thought about [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IDN-utopia-greek.jpg) ?